# How to find how many Amperes does a equipment use?

Tags: watts, ampere-hour

In the specification of this miner https://www.asicminervalue.com/miners/bitmain/antminer-s9j-14-5th it says it uses `1350W` power with `12V` electricity. I like to know how can I find how many Amperes this machine uses?

In general I like to know with a electricity supply around `380V` and `150A` how many of these machines can be run?

Comment: Hint: Watts = Volts x Amps

Comment: As P=VI, P=1350, V=12, that means that 1350/12 = I, so total current is 112.5A. Which is quite a bit. You need a good chunky wire to deliver that kind of current without significant heating of wire and voltage drops.

Comment: @Puffafish: Shouldn't 1350 be divided by 3600?

Comment: @user3486308 Why? You asked for amps at 12V to power 1250W. Assuming you're now talking about the second part of your question, 360V (not 3600) then there are other concerns: the unit you've linked to only operates at 12V, so you need to convert down to 12V first otherwise you'll just damage things.

Comment: @Puffafish: No I thought the 1350 is Watt per hour and maybe we should convert it to watt to second by dividing by 3600.

Comment: If you have 100 machines, they need 135000 W. If you supply them from 360 V you need a converter stepping down from 360 V to 12 V. The converter input current will be 135000/360 = 375 A and the converter output current will be 30 times larger (minus converter losses) which is 11.25 kA. And this is, as written before, 112.5 A per machine.

Comment: @Puffafish So If my input Ams is 150A in maximum, I can't run 100 of these machines? I must run about 40 of them?

Comment: Given modest inefficiencies converting 360 V to 12 V, perhaps 500 A at 360 V for 100 units. I'd recommend installing twice that capacity, though. You may need to expand later, and may as well plan in some room to grow. Silver plated copper bus bars will be your friend.

Comment: Also you may want to have a look at the graph to the right of the unit on the page you linked to. Apparently these units can't run at a profit unless you're getting your electricity at a very low rate. And if you're stepping it down, you will need to pay to the energy into the system (including that which is wasted in the conversion down to 12V) and energy used to cool the system.

Comment: @Puffafish: So with a electricity supplier of 360V~380V  and 150A, how many of these machines can be run? 40 or less?

Comment: @user3486308 1350 W is 1350 Joules/second. You don't divide it by 3600, because it is per second already.

Comment: @user3486308 using finger-in-air numbers about efficiencies of your DCDC, at 360V and 150A, that's 54kW, down to 12V, using a 80% converter (which may be better than you'll get), that's 43kW, so 32 units at most. Probably less by the time you've done other loses (such as wires etc), so I'd say you'd be lucky to get 30 running. And this assumes that no extra cooling is required. And that your power is free and reliable.

Comment: 380V x 150A makes 57kW. You realize that, if you put anything that consumes that much power in a room, you'll need a hell of a cooling system, which needs to be taken into account in your power budget? You realize you can't just design such a monster by asking random questions to random people on the internet if you are not yet able to make a simple division according to the consistency of units principles? I'm sure you can get one of these devices working on your desk.  I'm sure you *can't* design a cluster of 30 of those, let alone making it profitable.

Comment: Is that 380V supply single phase or three phase?

Comment: I think you're a little bit late to the bitcoin mining. You're most certainly going to lose money by doing whatever you're going to do and waste a lot of energy at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Power= Voltage * Current

1. You can not plug in 360V as input directly to device mentioned, It should be buck down to 12V somehow.
2. Each unit will draw 112.5A of current, whether you connect 1 unit or 100 units
3. For 100 units you require 112.5*100 A current.

Comment: So if I have an electricity supply with 360V~380V and 150A, how many of this machine I can run?

Comment: Total power = 360V * 150A = 54000W. Assume converter is only 80% Efficient. Total available power will be 43200W. One unit consumes 1350W so 43200/1350 = 32 Units. But you can not connect maximum load. Keep some buffer. Approximately you can connect 26-28 devices with cooling arrangements.